# What is OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor?

Tags: python, sockets, webserver, oserror

I'm trying to create a simple Web server in Python. I can see an HTML file in a browser through the server, which is what I'm trying to achieve, but it's not nice and neat with the error popping up every time. Here is the relevant server code:

```py
from socket import *

serverPort = 1200
serverSocket: socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:
    
    print('Ready to serve...')
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    print('connectionSocket is:', connectionSocket)
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        filename: bytes = message.split()[1]
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read()
        
        connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n'.encode('UTF-8'))
       
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i].encode())
        connectionSocket.send("\r\n".encode())
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
       
        connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'.encode('UTF-8'))
        connectionSocket.send("<html><head></head><body><h1>404 Not Found</h1></body></html> ".encode('UTF-8'))
        
    serverSocket.close()
sys.exit()
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/PycharmProjects/firstPy/proj1.py", line 15, in <module>
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 293, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

From my understanding of this error, it occurs because you are trying to access a file that is not open yet. I presume in this case my socket is not connecting properly?

The part that confuses me is that I can still access the HTML even if it comes up with an error. So I presume that it's connecting properly or at least partially.

I also thought it might be to do with the version of Python I'm running (3.9) and so there's a different syntax I should be using, but I can't find a problem there too.

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the serverSocket after reading only part of the data

```
serverSocket.close()
```

should be outside the loop